# How to obtain nodes count and nodes left in docplex (using CPLEX 12.20 and Python 3.8)

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I solving a MILP problem as given below using Python 3.8 and CPLEX 12.20. I want to obtain the number of nodes and nodes left. The details of the codes are as follows:

---

n_xvars=2
n_yvars=2

#Create model:
my_MILP=Model(name='MILP example')

## Defining variables:

x_vars={i+1:my_MILP.continuous_var(name='x_{}'.format(i+1),lb=-20,ub=20) for i in range(n_xvars)}

y_vars={i+1:my_MILP.integer_var(name='y_{}'.format(i+1),lb=-20,ub=20) for i in range(n_yvars)}

## Adding constraints:

my_MILP.add_constraint(x_vars[1]+4*x_vars[2]>=-5)
my_MILP.add_constraint(x_vars[1]-y_vars[2]<=5)
my_MILP.add_constraint(x_vars[1]+3*y_vars[1]-10*y_vars[2]<=10)
my_MILP.add_constraint(x_vars[1]+2*x_vars[2]-3*y_vars[1]+4*y_vars[2]<=2)

## Defining objective function:

obj=x_vars[1]+5*x_vars[2]+6*y_vars[1]-2*y_vars[2]
my_MILP.minimize(obj)

## Model information

my_MILP.print_information()
print(my_MILP.export_as_lp_string())

## Solving and solution

my_MILP.solve()
my_MILP.print_solution()

---

I have used a few codes such as

nd_count=my_MILP.get_solve_details().nodes_processed
nd_left=my_MILP.get_solve_details().nodes_left

but I am getting errors like

AttributeError: 'SolveDetails' object has no attribute 'nodes_left'
AttributeError: 'SolveDetails' object has no attribute 'nodes_processed'

I request the community to please help me obtain the node count and nodes left for MILP, IP, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want can be seen in the CPLEX log as follows:

```
Tried aggregator 1 time. 
Presolve time =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: none, using 1 thread.
Root relaxation solution time = 0.00 sec (0.00 ticks)

         Nodes                                 Cuts/   
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer     Best Bound    ItCnt    Gap
*     0+    0                            0.0000     3261.8212        8     ---
*     0+    0                         3148.0000     3261.8212        8    3.62%
      0     0     3254.5370     7     3148.0000       Cuts: 5       14    3.38%
      0     0     3246.0185     7     3148.0000       Cuts: 3       24    3.11%
*     0+    0                         3158.0000     3246.0185       24    2.79%
      0     0     3245.3465     9     3158.0000       Cuts: 5       27    2.77%
      0     0     3243.4477     9     3158.0000       Cuts: 5       32    2.71%
      0     0     3242.9809    10     3158.0000     Covers: 3       36    2.69%
      0     0     3242.8397    11     3158.0000     Covers: 1       37    2.69%
      0     0     3242.7428    11     3158.0000       Cuts: 3       39    2.68%
      0     2     3242.7428    11     3158.0000     3242.7428       39    2.68%
     10    11     3199.1875     2     3158.0000     3215.1261       73    1.81%
*    20+   11                         3168.0000     3215.1261       89    1.49%
     20    13     3179.0028     5     3168.0000     3215.1261       89    1.49%
     30    15     3179.9091     3     3168.0000     3197.5227      113    0.93%
*    39     3      integral     0     3186.0000     3197.3990      126    0.36%
     40     3     3193.7500     1     3186.0000     3197.3990      128    0.36% 

Cover cuts applied:  9
Zero-half cuts applied:  2
Gomory fractional cuts applied:  1

Solution pool: 5 solutions saved. 
MIP-Integer optimal solution:  Objective =   3.1860000000e+03
Solution time =    0.01 sec.  (0.00 ticks)  Iterations = 131   Nodes = 44
```

The first and the second columns most likely are what you are looking for. In the above example, CPLEX found the optimal objective function value of 3.1860000000e+03 after exploring 44 nodes and performing 131 (dual simplex) iterations. Also, as far as I know, the log information can still be invoked through the optimization process via its appropriate callbacks.

Comment: For more details please, see this [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=mip-progress-reports-interpreting-node-log).

Comment: Many thanks A.Omidi. Since I am running optimization processes in a loop that is why I think of callbacks commands to get them Do you have any idea for it?

Comment: @MohammadSamiullah, I do not have more experience with log callback, but I think what you are looking for would be an `informational callback`. Also, [this](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/tree/master/examples/mp/callbacks) link is a good starting point. Also, `mipex4.py` in your CPLEX directory is an introduction to this.

Comment: Thank you so much, A.Omidi.